# Retrieving a PerformancePoint dashboard in Windows 8 application

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint

I am using SharePoint 2013 and Windows 8 application.

Is it possible to connect to a PerformancePoint dashboard via the application and display items like the dashboard, graphs with drill to/drill down options?

I have no real experience with SP 2013 and PerformancePoint, the dashboard will be created by others. I need to connect to it and retrieve items.

Can you point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your Windows 8 application it hard to answer this. To truly use PerformancePoint for what it is intended, the Windows 8 application would need to expose the data thought an SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) Data Cube.

If it does you can build a PerformancePoint dashboard based on the cube's data. If you do not have an SSAS Cube, PerformancePoint may not be the solution for you.

I recommend reading this article on MSDN to get an overview of PerformancePoint, [PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559635.aspx).